# Rails Capistrano rbenv Puma bundle: Command not found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, capistrano, rbenv, puma

I'm trying to run cap staging deploy to an AWS instance, which is our staging server. Everything works, including bundle install... But when it gets to running the Puma server it fails:

```
Command: cd /home/ubuntu/medcordance/current && ( export RBENV_ROOT="$HOME/.rbenv" RBENV_VERSION="2.5.0" RACK_ENV="staging" ; bundle exec puma -C /home/ubuntu/app_name/shared/puma.rb --daemon )

 DEBUG [02658949]   bash: bundle: command not found
```

I've checked high and low for a solution. I can't find one. I ran gem install bundler, I confirmed that bundler is installed, I've configured Capistrano with every setting I know should work, and I still can't find a solution to this.

Capfile:

```
# Load DSL and set up stages
require "capistrano/setup"

# Include default deployment tasks
require "capistrano/deploy"

# Load the SCM plugin appropriate to your project:
#
# require "capistrano/scm/hg"
# install_plugin Capistrano::SCM::Hg
# or
# require "capistrano/scm/svn"
# install_plugin Capistrano::SCM::Svn
# or
require "capistrano/scm/git"
install_plugin Capistrano::SCM::Git

# Include tasks from other gems included in your Gemfile
#
# For documentation on these, see for example:
#
#   https://github.com/capistrano/rvm
#   https://github.com/capistrano/rbenv
#   https://github.com/capistrano/chruby
#   https://github.com/capistrano/bundler
#   https://github.com/capistrano/rails
#   https://github.com/capistrano/passenger
#
require 'capistrano/rails'
# require "capistrano/rvm"
require "capistrano/rbenv"
require "capistrano/bundler"
# require "capistrano/chruby"
require "capistrano/rails/assets"
require "capistrano/rails/migrations"

require "capistrano/puma"
install_plugin Capistrano::Puma  # Default puma tasks

# Load custom tasks from `lib/capistrano/tasks` if you have any defined
Dir.glob("lib/capistrano/tasks/*.rake").each { |r| import r }
```

Deploy:

```
lock "~> 3.10.1"

set :application, "app_name"
set :repo_url, "my bitbucket"
set :branch, 'master'

set :use_sudo, true

set :rbenv_type, :user
set :rbenv_ruby, '2.5.0'
set :rbenv_prefix, "RBENV_ROOT=#{fetch(:rbenv_path)} RBENV_VERSION=#{fetch(:rbenv_ruby)} #{fetch(:rbenv_path)}/bin/rbenv exec"
set :rbenv_map_bins, %w{rake gem bundle ruby rails}
set :rbenv_roles, :all # default value

# Default branch is :master
# ask :branch, `git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD`.chomp

# Default deploy_to directory is /var/www/my_app_name
set :deploy_to, "/home/ubuntu/app_name"
```

Comment: Where is `bundle` installed? Maybe that script doesn't have it in `$PATH`. Use `which bundle` and then in the script make sure that's in `echo $PATH`.

Comment: /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/shims/bundle

How do I make sure it's in the echo path?

Comment: Edit whatever script it is that failed and add `echo $PATH` there.

Comment: I'm sorry, that doesn't help me, can you be more specific?

Comment: Maybe someone that knows Capistrano will be able to help better. But from my perspective, you have a log file that contains an error saying `bundle` can't be found. That log file is created by some script. You haven't specified which. My suggestion is that you find that script and edit it to see what it has in its `PATH` environment variable. I'd put money on it not containing `/home/ubuntu/.rbenv/shims`.

Answer (score 2):

Figured it out. Turned out to be this single line in my config/deploy.rb file:

```
set :rbenv_map_bins, %w{rake gem bundle ruby rails}
```

By removing that it works...

Comment: Are you sure that's it? The reason I ask is that capistrano-rbenv itself sets that identical value by default, so I am surprised that setting (or not setting) it in your deploy.rb has any real effect. See: https://github.com/capistrano/rbenv/blob/c029e4128e4a8f25adda35795f5729bd4f62e51f/lib/capistrano/tasks/rbenv.rake#L47

Comment: Same for me, I had to remove the line and it worked

Answer (score 0):

For me, adding the following line to `config/deploy.rb`

```
append :asdf_map_ruby_bins, 'puma', 'pumactl' # I use asdf to manage ruby plugins

# Or
# append :rbenv_map_bins, 'puma', 'pumactl' if you're using Rbenv, like OP
```

solved the issue. Hope it helps someone!

Reference: https://github.com/seuros/capistrano-puma/issues/188

NB* `append` is the new Capistrano syntax, `set` still works though